# SQL Join issue with 3 tables and a subquery

Tags: sqlplus, oracle12c

Tables Involved: 
account, user, service, accesshist

I want to include all records in the account table, and only the data from the other tables when it exists.

Count from account:  5064

rows returned from query below: 4915

```
select u.last_name, u.first_name, a.username, ll.mxlogin, si.servicename, a.islockedout
from account a
join service si on a.serviceid = si.serviceid
left outer join user u on u.loginid = a.username
left outer join(select max(loginattemptdate) as MxLogin, usernameattempted from accesshist where isloginsuccessful = 1
group by usernameattempted) ll
on a.username = ll.usernameattempted
where a.isenabled = 1
order by ll.mxlogin, u.last_name
```

I've narrowed it down that the subquery join is the part causing the number of rows to be reduced, but I am unsure how to correct it.  Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the first join to a left outer join?

```
 select u.last_name, u.first_name, a.username, ll.mxlogin, si.servicename, a.islockedout
    from account a
    left outer join service si on a.serviceid = si.serviceid
```

Comment: I could, but it doesn't make a difference.  There are only 4 service codes and the service code column has a null constraint in the account table.

Comment: I would just start simplifying the problem.  Remove the sub-select and just join to accesshist. change all joins to left outer join  Remove ll.mxlogin, the where clause, and order by.